# Android Push Notification. Migration from Parce.com to Amazon SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, amazon-sns

I need to migrate push notification service from Parse to Amazon SNS at Android project.

As you know to use AmazonWS you need api_key of Firebase project.
So I need to import google project in Firebase console.

But it really important for me to know if push notification from Parse will work well after convertation to Firebase project. Please, let me know if smbd try it before.